# Use CSS to hide adjacent DIV based on content

Tags: html, css

Here are two potential situations in my HTML:

```
<div class="ptb_sold">
    <span class="ptb_one_line">Sold</span>
</div>
<div class="ptb_link_button">
    <a class="ptb_link_button" target="_blank" href="https://test.html">Click to Register</a>
</div>
```

```
<div class="ptb_sold"></div>
<div class="ptb_link_button">
    <a class="ptb_link_button" target="_blank" href="https://test.html">Click to Register</a>
</div>
```

My goal is to hide "ptb_link_button" in the first one, but allow the "ptb_link_button" div to display in the second example.  Basically, if the item is sold, I do not want to display the "Register" button.

I initially thought this would work:

```css
div.ptb_sold:empty+.ptb_link_button {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="ptb_sold">
  <span class="ptb_one_line">Sold</span>
</div>
<div class="ptb_link_button">
  <a class="ptb_link_button" target="_blank" href="https://test.html">Click to Register - Link one</a>
</div>

<div class="ptb_sold"></div>
<div class="ptb_link_button">
  <a class="ptb_link_button" target="_blank" href="https://test.html">Click to Register - Link two</a>
</div>
```

But unfortunately it does not.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: In order to disambiguate the links, when I made the snippet to show that your code works I amended the link-text, adding " - Link one" and " - Link two"

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  I just learned that ":empty" does not ignore whitespace, which I guess still exists in the actual HTML I'm working with.  At least you've confirmed it can work.

Comment: This was one of the [mistakes of CSS](https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/mistakes), though as noted in that link it's "[fixed in spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-4/#the-empty-pseudo)," though not yet implemented according to MDN's [compatibility table for `:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty#browser_compatibility).

Comment: Is there a specific reason you want to use css to achieve that ? Just curious, because in usual scenario as you describe (condition about HTML content), you either do it client side with JavaScript or  server side to generate the page and display it like you want.

Comment: The HTML is being generated by a 3rd party plugin.  I don't want to modify the plugin because then I'd have to implement the changes every time the plugin is updated.  I am using a combination of CSS and JavaScript to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then I think this would be the approach:

```
// Hides the button if sold
div.ptb_sold + .ptb_link_button a.ptb_link_button {
  display: none;
}
// Show the button if not sold
div.ptb_sold:empty + .ptb_link_button a.ptb_link_button {
  display: block;
}
```

Example - https://jsfiddle.net/4o1gvnjx/

Also, I would consider changing the class name of the container for the button to be something like 'ptb_link_button-container' to avoid confusion. That way, the CSS selector would be more streamlined.

Comment: Thanks for understanding what I wanted (and not my example!)  I found that :empty does not ignore whitespace, but I wrote a simple jQuery routine that removes the whitespace from from the div and now it works on the site.